# How to set up consition that all elements of one arrays must be equal to at least one element of the another array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, match

Transforming roman numerals into numbers! A user enter his one roman number, and the code transfers his/her roman number into classic number.

```
var roman = prompt("Enter roman number", roman);
var romandigits = roman.toString().split(""); // spliting roman number entered into an array!
let romannumerals = ["M", "D", "C", "L", "X", "V", "I"];
```

Now condition that suppose to be set is:
ALL elements of the array romandigits have to be equal to AT LEAST one element of the array romannumerals!

Comment: `romandigits.every(s => romannumerals.includes(s));` see: [Array.prototype.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a set of romannumerals

```
let numeralSet = new Set(romannumerals);
```

Then you can check that each digit is in that set

```
let badDigits = romanDigits.filter((c) => !numeralSet.has(c))
```

and then check whether there are any badDigits:

```
if (badDigits.length) {
    console.error(`Invalid roman number ${roman} contains non-digits ${badDigits}`);
}
```

So putting it all together

```
let roman = prompt("Enter roman number");
let romandigits = [...roman];
let romannumerals = ["M", "D", "C", "L", "X", "V", "I"];
let numeralSet = new Set(romannumerals);
let badDigits = romandigits.filter((c) => !numeralSet.has(c))
if (badDigits.length) {
    console.error(`Invalid roman number ${roman} contains non-digits ${badDigits}`);
} else {
    console.log(`${roman} is OK`);
}
```